# Issues with the Dorian mode

Tags: theory

In Dorian mode we have a flat 3rd. and a flat 7th. Does the flattening refer to changing a major to a minor or does it refer to lowering a note by one fret to make it a flat (as in sharp/flat). Peter E

Answer (score 1):

The basic major scale is the datum point. Changes which make modes and minors are notated from those major notes.

So, saying C Dorian has a ♭3 it says E♭ rather than E♮, and ♭7 of B♭ instead of the 'standard' B.

Both notes, as it happens are majors changed to minors - M3>m3, M7>m7.

Moving any note down one fret on guitar essentially flattens it - although its new name may not reflect that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, are you saying that E major note, and E major chord are both reduced to a minor, surely they are both different items and sound differently?

Comment: Theere is no such thing as an 'E major note'. There's an 'E natural', which is the 3rd in key C - and is E&natural;. E major chord (or E minr chord) has nothing to do with all of this.

Answer (score 1):

"Flattening" a  note refers to lowering that note by a half step; the term isn't key-dependent. For example, E->Eb, F->E, F#->F, and F##->F# (though I can't think of a practical example); when flattening (also Eb->Ebb).

There is a bit of subtlety in this. Flattening or sharpening a note does not change the note name.  (Notational practice doesn't generally assume equal-temperament where Cb=B enharmonically. Lots of music notation practice tends to ignore enharmonic equivalence; B#, C, and Cb are assumed to be three different notes.)

The same thing applies to the term "sharpening";  notes are raised a half step.

Extra comment: some English idiolects prefer to use "flat" or "sharp" as a verb rather than "flatten" or "sharpen" so this may occur in one's reading. (I prefer the "en" form so as to make it clear that I'm using a verb. Sightreading is important in ordinary reading as well as in music.)

Comment: Second para. is confusing!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think you understand it. The "flat" would be lowering a major to a minor interval. A bit more detail follows.

Dorian mode has a *minor* third and *minor* seventh above the tonic.

Whether sharps and flats are involved depends on the key signature and which tone is the tonic.

If you were in `D` dorian with a key signature of no sharps and flats, you would not use *any* flats to spell the third and seventh tones of the scale.

But, a lot of chord and scale notation uses a major chord or scale as a reference point. If you were in `C` major with a key signature of no sharps and flats and wanted to change the scale to `C` dorian, you would put flats on the third and seventh, the `E` and `B`.

When speaking generically about dorian mode, it better to use the interval name, like: dorian mode has a *minor third* above the tonic.

When the tones are spelled out, then use sharps and flats, like: the third above the tonic in `C` dorian is `E` flat.

You can also say *lowered* or *raised* rather than *flat* or *sharp* to avoid awkward thinks like a "sharp 5th" in `E` flat major (where the *raised* fifth will actually be spelled `B` *natural*!) Those lowerings and raisings are by half step (one fret on guitar.)

The common lingo will use "sharp" and "flat" regardless whether the actual spellings use sharps or flats. It's just a short hand naming, but it's confusing in the beginning. When you learn proper interval names and key signatures and such you will get used to it.